# How can I accurately (yet adaptively) detect groups of dark pixels in a row?

Tags: arrays, image, image-processing, pixel, difference

Imagine that I need to write a program that takes an image and looks for rows of pixels that contain groups of dark pixels.  Below is an example image.

[image]

Keep in mind that this example is an ideal scenario; my goal is to be able to accomplish this using a standard phone camera or webcam with lighting/contrast/focus that varies.  The image won't always be perfectly binary.

Every row is an array of smaller arrays(the pixels) that contain RGBA data.  The format of a pixel is: `[r, g, b, a]`

Here's an example row of pixels:

`[[161, 160, 138, 255], [160, 162, 134, 255], [160, 162, 134, 255], [152, 163, 137, 255], [152, 163, 137, 255], [152, 163, 137, 255]]`

Note that a typical row array would be much larger than this, with lengths up to 1024.

What I want to do is be able to collect the groups of pixels that make up the dark groups in the row.

So in the end I'll want something like this pseudocode:

```
print groups

// [[pixel, pixel, pixel, pixel], [pixel, pixel, pixel, pixel], [pixel, pixel, pixel, pixel], [pixel, pixel, pixel, pixel], [pixel, pixel, pixel, pixel]]

groups.length

// 5
```

The issue is that while it would be easy enough to just look for pixels that have a brightness below a threshold, poor lighting may mean that other non-black pixels may be below an arbitrary threshold.  At the same time, I can not always look for pixels with a value of absolute 0 since, realistically, not every visually black pixels will have a value of 0.

I was thinking of getting around this by iterating through a row and comparing each pixel to the one before it; if it was more than 80% different than the last one then it would be counted as a contrasting pixel and thus the beginning of a group.  The next time there is a difference of 80% or more would mean the end of a pixel group.  This would be great since it could detect rows of varying colors, or even an inverted version of my example.

However, the gaping flaw in this idea is that if the program came across a  pixel with a value of 0 and the previous one was 250(hence the start of a pixel group), but then the following pixel had a value of 2 that would technically be a 200% difference and would be considered the end of a pixel group(which is wrong).

Having an arbitrary threshold still technically works but it's not very adaptive.  Collecting an average value for the threshold as I iterate through a row helps, but it's still not perfect.  I feel that my idea of looking for drastic changes between pixels would be more extensible but I'm not sure if I should continue down that path if there isn't a good solution to it.  Are there any other techniques for getting this kind of data from an image?

Example code is welcome in any language, though I'd prefer Ruby, JavaScript, CoffeeScript, or Python.

Comment: I assume you're actually working in HSI color space when you talk about looking for pixels with a low intensity.  You could also try working in YCbCr color space and looking at the Cb and Cr values.  (Cb-128)*(Cb-128) + (Cr-128)*(Cr-128) < some value to identify dark pixels.  Also, some methods calculate the dark pixel threshold as some factor times the average image intensity or more adaptively as some factor times the average intensity in a moving window.  You would still need at least a second test to be sure the average intensity in the moving window is above some value.

Comment: I am converting pixels to HSL, though I'm not doing the HS part since they don't matter and would be a waste of computing time.  It's not clear to me how calculating Cb/Cr would be better than calculating L.  I like the idea of a window, though I imagine it would impact performance.  I'd have to try it out.

Comment: The methods that use YCbCr are computationally expensive, and probably not what you want.  I'm wondering about your use of HSI, though.  Might you also want to look at saturation?  If you are worried about identifying pixels that have a low intensity because of poor lighting, maybe saturation could give you another clue.